# Wrapping Hashmap with method malformed encoding

Tags: java, encoding, hashmap

I have a hashmap that contains labels for different languages. Previously I used this to populate my translated objects with the translation directly from the map that worked fine.

```
     Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
        m.put("sv", "Läs mer");
//...
t.setLabel(m.getOrDefault(language, ""))
```

Now sometimes, my key can also contain the country, "sv_SE", so I wrote a wrapper method for this:

```
private static String getLabel(String key) {
    String value = m.get(key);
    if (value == null) {
        int i = key.indexOf("_");
        if (i > 0) {
            value = m.getOrDefault(key.substring(0, i), "");
        } else {
            value = "";
        }
    }
    if (!key.equals("en") && value.equals("")) {
        System.out.println("WARN: Used \"\" label for " + key );
    }
    return value;
}
```

However, when I started using this wrapper, non english characters gets malformed in the .json file I write this content to later:

```
"L��s mer"
```

What is going on here? The only thing I did was adding this wrapper method.

Comment: Were you able to write non-english characters to .json file correctly before this change ?

Comment: Yes I was. I even tried removing this wrapper method and yep, it still works...

Comment: Can you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: @tdhtrhfgh: nothing in that method manipulates `value`, so the problem must lie with some other code. Is it possible that only now do you return wrong values that always existed but you never used (because they were "hidden" behind a `sv_SE` key?)

Comment: I ran the code through debugger and the value looks correct. I use the same map in both cases. I tried even adding a key with sv_SE and the same value, stepped through debugger so all looks fine, still the same issue.

Comment: @tdhtrhfgh: that reinforces my idea that the method is not the problem. At some point you mis-handle character encodings (possibly at the last step that outputs the text). The two weird-question-marks indicate that the `String` was UTF-8 encoded when something expected a different (single-byte) encoding.

Comment: @joachimSauer Yes I think so to, but I don't see how this method can mess upp the encoding. The t object that uses the label is a string anyway.

Comment: @tdhtrhfgh: so where **exactly** do you see the value `"L��s mer"` and how does it get there? Whatever puts it there (or whatever interprets it from there) does something wrong (possibly both).

Comment: Before you put any more effort into making a Map, read about the [ResourceBundle class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ResourceBundle.html).  You are attempting to reinvent what ResourceBundle already does quite well.